# Strange django behavior when adding fields to models

Tags: python, django, django-south

I need a custom ordering for one of my models. So in Meta class, I used the following documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to

According to the warning at the end of that section that says 
Changing order_with_respect_to

> order_with_respect_to adds an additional field/database column named
>   _order, so be sure to make and apply the appropriate migrations if you add or change order_with_respect_to after your initial migrate.

I added order_with_respect_to,

```
 class Meta(object):
        order_with_respect_to = 'group'
        unique_together = (
            ('name', 'slug'),
        )
```

Then the o/p of

```
./manage.py schemamigration app_name --auto
```

gives me

```
- Added field _order on search.Filter
Created 0025_auto__del_field_filter__order.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate search
```

It adds the field but created auto__del?

Comment: `0025_auto__del_field_filter__order.py` is just the name of the migration file. Unless it actualy contains other operations in the `forwards` method, it only adds the `_order` field. I don't know how south generates the file name exactly, so I can't tell you why it's named like that. Btw, you're using the documentation for 1.7 while you're using Django <= 1.6. There have been quite a few changes in 1.7, so it might be a good idea to select the appropriate version in the bottom-right corner.

Comment: yes, looking at the forward method in the generated migration will help you know what are the operations

Comment: Hmm, I will check the forward method in the migration file. Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: Yes, as you said. The forwarder method was adding the right tables :) I need to mark this solved